# React Countdown setInterval not working ? Waiting for your solutions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [timerHours, setTimerHours] = useState('00');
  const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState('00');
  const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState('00');

  const startTimer = (duration) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      var seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
      minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
      hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

      hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
      minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0) {
        clearInterval();
      }
      else {
        setTimerHours(hours);
        setTimerMinutes(minutes);
        setTimerSeconds(seconds);
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    startTimer(80214523);
    return () => {
      clearInterval()
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {timerHours} : {timerMinutes} : {timerSeconds}
    </div>
  );
}
```

code structure like this. There is no problem getting the hour, minute and second information. The countdown is not working.

Example : https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-aryabhata-r1dwo?file=/src/App.js:0-1101

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the useeffect hook is run every time the state is updated, then you countdown is started with same start point all the time because you use a constant

I found an example here
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-countdown-timer-react-hooks

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you. I tested the application at the address you sent, but still no results.